# Spring 3 MVC session is lost after external redirect

Tags: session, redirect, spring-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

I have a Spring 3 MVC app and part of the app requires a redirect to a 3rd party payment site and that payment site redirects back to my app after it's done.  The problem is that Spring seems to create a new session instead of using the old one and erases all the data previously stored in the session.  This creates massive problems for my app and I'm wondering if there is a way to preserve the session after external redirect?

Also, cookie are enabled on my browser and I indeed verified that the jsessionid value in the cookie changes after the redirect, indicating a new session overwriting the old one.

Comment: @Vokuhella I am facing the same issue. can you please let me know if you have fixed the issue? or you got any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: @vokuhella exactly same problem i am facing in production, please let me know the solution if you got already

Comment: have the same issue, let me know if any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the following info:

1. After coming back from the 3rd party site, does your app use a different domain/sub domain from what it uses before redirecting to the 3rd party site?
2. Is there a possibility that your session timeout value is so low that the session expires by the time the user returns to your app?
3. Does your app use frames having onunload events that invalidate the session?

Comment: 1.  Nope. Same domain.  2. Timeout is long enough.  3. I don't use frames in the app.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing a similar problem. Thanks