# Session lost while redirecting from payment site - MVC

Tags: session, redirect, model-view-controller

In my razor mvc application, I am storing some values to the session variables. After that i am redirecting to the 3rd party payment site. Once i am done with the payment i am again coming back to my application. In this time, i am loosing all the session variables.

This issue is happening only in the production server. This is working fine in my development environment.

I have [Spring 3 MVC session is lost after external redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865423/spring-3-mvc-session-is-lost-after-external-redirect)

But i didn't see any solution in this post.

I am using IIS 7.5 with dedicated application pool.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608362/chrome-losing-cookies) but was only getting it with chrome. so this might not help you.

Basically my cookies we beening set like www.mysite.com or .mysite.com. and on the redirect from my payment site, like you, it was being lost

To fix i explictly set the cookie domain to www.mysite.com and this resloved my issue.